# addonevent fires only for the first ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf-2

We have a `addonEvent` function to perform some scripts after ajax call.
But if there are more than one ajax calls, the scripts are not executed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function(data) { 
if (data.status === 'success') {
    // do something
}
});
});
```

Is there any way to execute the scripts?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `.live()`? Why are you hooking on `begin` instead of `success`?

Comment: I'm sorry it was success, not begin!

Comment: Why don't you want to use `.live()`? Are you getting any JS errors in browser's JS console? (note that it are 2 questions)

Comment: .live() doesn't work in IE for some functions with change event

Comment: Also mentioned in this link http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html

Comment: Yes I get a general JS error in console saying "Syntax error" in line 1 void();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try placing the `addOnEvent` inside the

```
$(window).load(function() {

});
```

Comment: For some reason it's not working again, I'm trying to figure out why?

Comment: ctrl + F5 maybe ? cache issues? also, look at the console maybe you got some errors...

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with above, it was working earlier because I used .live()

Comment: are you sure that you fire a f:ajax event? or you are using jQuery events?

Comment: Yes it's an f:ajax called more than once without reloading page